# Run Electron main process from URL

Tags: electron

I am using `webpack-dev-server` to build and serve an electron app. I am using the multi-target support so it builds and serves both the Renderer and Main files. These are available at http://localhost:8080/, in my case the Main entry point is http://localhost:8080/background.js, and the Renderer `index.html` is http://localhost:8080/ which loads http://localhost:8080/js/main.js.

`webpack-dev-server` only builds the files in memory - they are never written to disk. However Electron only seems to run its Main process from files on disk. I.e. if I run `electron path/to/background.js` it works fine, but that file doesn't exist when using `webpack-dev-server`. If I run `electron http://localhost:8080/` it just loads the Renderer `index.html` and never runs `background.js`.

Basically I want to do

```
electron http://localhost:8080/background.js
```

and have it download and run that file as the Main process. That command doesn't work (it just opens the `background.js` file as text. Is there any way to achieve this short of doing it manually with curl or whatever?

Comment: cjs by default doesn't support import from remote url. You should have configure someway to place physical file to start main process. further, node.js does not able to reload modules on demand, so devserver refresh won't affect until restart process again.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on a workaround - you can make `webpack-dev-server` serve its output from memory *and* write the files to disk. I added [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-) to the webpack config for my Main process:

```
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true
  }
```

Note that due to [a bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2627) you need to add it to your Renderer config too, even though you don't need those files, otherwise nothing gets written.